# for loop function for array object only finds one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array called Cards that on console log looks like

```
    Array[3]
     0: Object
     1: Object
     2: Object
```

each of these has a name: which I am using to reference it 
want to find it reference the obejct I have

```
var FoundInArray = [];
        function CheckIndexArray(ArraySearch, array) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i].name === ArraySearch) {
                    FoundInArray = array[i];
                    return true
                    break
               } else {return false;}                    }
        }
         if (CheckIndexArray(document.getElementById("userInput").value, Cards) == true) {
             console.log(FoundInArray);
```

the 3 names are ADAM, Arron Shamira, Adrian Omarsh  this however only finds ADAM if I search the other two it doesn't find them. The question is why???

Comment: You are returning false, thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, your `for` loop breaks after 1st iteration because of `else {return false;}`

Also, you can look into `Array.find()` or `Array.filter`.

#### array.find

This will return first matching value or `undefined`

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'foo', id:1},
  {name: 'foo', id:2},
  {name: 'bar', id:3},
  {name: 'test', id:4}
]
var searchName = "foo";
var r = arr.find(function(x){ return x.name === searchName});
console.log(r)
```

#### array.filter

This will return you all matching values or `[]`

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'foo', id:1},
  {name: 'foo', id:2},
  {name: 'bar', id:3},
  {name: 'test', id:4}
]
var searchName = "foo";
var r = arr.filter(function(x){ return x.name === searchName});
console.log(r)
```

Also if the purpose is only to check the existence of some value, you can even try `array.some`

#### Array.some

Unlike previously mentioned methods, this returns a boolean value. If you do not have use for value, you can even use this method.

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'foo', id:1},
  {name: 'foo', id:2},
  {name: 'bar', id:3},
  {name: 'test', id:4}
]
var searchName = "foo";
var isAvailable = arr.some(function(x){ return x.name === searchName});
console.log(isAvailable)

searchName = "foo123";
isAvailable = arr.some(function(x){ return x.name === searchName});
console.log(isAvailable)
```

Comment: Thanks That totally helped me past the section i was on and you explained it really well also the code snippets helped a lot thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `return false`, it breaks the loop.

also there are better ways of filtering an array like `array.filter()` or `array.find()`

src: [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)